# Calculate mean for selected rows for selected columns in pandas data frame，but end up with some weird number

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find the mean for certain column of the data frame in python, but then I ended up with some really weird number. Can someone explain this to me?
I want the mean for column a,b,c

```
k = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 0, 3,'kk'], [4, 5, 6,'kk'], [7, 20, 9,'k'],[3, 2, 9,'k']]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c','type'])
k
```

which returns

```
    a   b   c   type
0   1   0   3   kk
1   4   5   6   kk
2   7   20  9   k
3   3   2   9   k
```

I want the mean for each column except the column 'type'

```
 k[['a','b','c']].mean()
```

and this give me

```
a     368.25
b    1300.50
c     924.75
dtype: float64
```

I am so confused! Can someone explain this to me ?

Answer (score 3):

This is the problem with creating the `numpy` array with mixed datatypes. Each sub-lists are now have a data type of `Object` and the same is being converted into data frame.

So, now DataFrame also will hold the same data type as in array.

See the below snippet:

```
k = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 0, 3,'kk'], [4, 5, 6,'kk'], [7, 20, 9,'k'],[3, 2, 9,'k']]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c','type'])

print(k.dtypes)

a       object
b       object
c       object
type    object
dtype: object
```

But you can think, how the mean is getting calculated over the string objects. This is again the power of numpy.

For example, take **column a**:

when you apply mean, it is trying the below operation,

`np.sum(array) / len(array)`

```
print(np.sum(k["a"]))

'1473'

print(np.len(k["a"]))

4

print(np.mean(k["a"]))

368.25
```

Now, 368.25 is nothing but `1473 / 4`.

For Column b, it will be 05202 / 4 = 1300.5.

So, when you create a Dataframe, create with list of lists or in a dictionary form which will assign the data types according to the elements.

```
k = pd.DataFrame(([[1, 0, 3,'kk'], [4, 5, 6,'kk'], [7, 20, 9,'k'],[3, 2, 9,'k']]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c','type'])

print(k.dtypes)

a        int64
b        int64
c        int64
type    object
dtype: object


print(k.mean())

a    3.75
b    6.75
c    6.75
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

If we look at the type of variables stored in the dataframe, we find that they're stored as objects.

```
print(k.dtypes)
```

```
a    object
b    object
c    object
d    object
dtype: object
```

This means that since you've stored a string in one of the columns, the entire dataframe is being stored as objects. There is a number associated to each character, and I believe you're getting a mean of some of those numbers (although I haven't been able to figure out how you got those numbers).

For example, if we look at the numerical value assigned to the string '0' :

```
ord('0')
```

```
48
```

We see it has the numerical value of 48.

In order to get the mean you're looking for, you'll need to change the type.

Try :

```
b = k[['a', 'b', 'c']].astype(int)
print(b.mean())
```

```
a    3.75
b    6.75
c    6.75
dtype: float64
```

edit : changed "strings" to "objects"

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your data is that you are mixing numbers with non numbers which is the 'k' for type.

Therefore your dataframe has type OBJECT and not integers.

Now I can't really explain on the low level how the numbers are generating such answer, however, the solution is:

***TLDR***;

`k[['a','b','c']].astype(int).mean()`

***Output:***

> ```
> a    3.75
> b    6.75
> c    6.75
> dtype: float64
> ```

And Welcome!